# expandable list and dialer

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I have an expandable list with a header and a number. I want to complete the action using a dialer whenever the number in the list is clicked. Im stuck with the getChildView method, I need to extract a numberString from the list. I tried numberString.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition) but I have an error "Cannot refer to a non-final variable groupPosition inside an inner class defined in a different method" Anyone have an idea how to do that ? thanks for help. Here is my code:

```
  public class ContactActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

 ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set up our adapter
        mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
      //  getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(this);
    }





    public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        // Sample data set.  children[i] contains the children (String[]) for groups[i].
        private String[] groups = { "General Enquiries", "Admissions Office"};
        private String[][] children = {
                { "+353-91-753161" },
                { "+353-91-742305", "+353-91-742262"}

        };

        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
        }

        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return children[groupPosition].length;
        }

        public TextView getGenericView() {
            // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
            AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 64);

            TextView textView = new TextView(ContactActivity.this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            // Center the text vertically
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
            // Set the text starting position
            textView.setPadding(70, 0, 0, 0);
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,20);
            return textView;
        }

        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = getGenericView();
            textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,15);

            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


                public void onClick(View view){
                    MyExpandableListAdapter numberString = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
                    numberString.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
                    Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + numberString);
                    Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);
                    startActivity(dial);
                    }
                });

            return textView;
        }

        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groups[groupPosition];
        }

        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groups.length;
        }

        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }


        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = getGenericView();
            textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());


            return textView;
        }


        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the data array directly (children in this case)

```
public void onClick(View view){
    String numberString = children[groupPosition][childPosition]
    Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + numberString);
    Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);
    startActivity(dial);
    }
});
```

Yes, adding `final` to the groupPosition and childPosition in the onClick will solve the problem

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

This is because, In Java you cannot access non-final variables inside the anonymous inner class of type `View.OnClickListener`